# java format particular date with T character

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

What is the correct form for parse this date?: `2015-05-29T00:00:00+02:00`

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date data = format.parse(dataValue);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
```

Notice that

- `MM` represents months, while `mm` represents minutes.
- if you want to have 24h format use `HH`, `hh` is for 12h format
- `XXX` represents time zone in format like `-08:00`
- to add literal like `T` in format you need to surround it with single quotes `'` like `'T'`

Comment: Thanks it works, can I ask you how can I do to change the format output in "yyyy-MM-dd" ?

Comment: If you have data as string in format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` and you want to convert it to format `yyyy-MM-dd` them I would say that simplest way would be using substring to pick this `yyyy-MM-dd` part. But if you for instance would like to convert it to something like `dd/MM/yyyy` then you would need to create another date formatter and simply `format` `Date` returned by original formatter. So your code can be like `String newFormat = newFormatter.format(oldFormatter.parse(stringDate))`.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Since the modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards, you are not required to use a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly to parse a date-time string conforming to the ISO 8601 standards. Your date-time string contains timezone offset string (`+02:00`) and therefore, the most appropriate type to be used to parse it is [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-05-29T00:00:00+02:00");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-05-29T00:00+02:00
```

For whatsoever reason, if you need an instance of `java.util.Date` from this object of `OffsetDateTime`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>